# What happens when a format specifier is not given to printf?

Tags: c, string

I came across this question in careercup about printf.

```
char *str = "hello";
printf("%s",str);
printf(str);
```

Second printf statement sometimes crash. I checked on various sites. Wrote the program to see if it actually does. But it does not. Also, I know that printf accepts an argument of type "const char* format" but format can be any constant string like "hello". But if I store it in a string str (which is ofcourse pointing to read-only memory). It is expected to work the same way. What exactly happens?

Can someone give a thorough explanation.

Comment: It works exactly the same way.  The first argument is always interpreted as a format string.

Comment: And the `str` variable contains no `%something` placeholders...

Comment: I can't see how the second statement would crash unless str is not null terminated.

Comment: @cup The second statement could crash if it contained argument specifiers, as there are no arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format specifiers in the format string are not required so:

```
printf("%s", "Hello world\n");
```

and

```
printf("Hello world\n");
```

will produce the same behavior.

However if the string in:

```
printf(str);
```

comes from an user input, you should use the `%s` specifier otherwise you are prone to format string attacks (the attacker could forge strings with `%x` to dump the stack and `%n` to overwrite memory).

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not *safe* to call `printf` with a dynamic format string:

```
void foo(char const * p)
{
    printf(p);   // !
}
```

You cannot tell from the program source code alone whether the program is correct. The correctness depends on the *value* of the string (i.e. it must not contain format specifiers), and it *may* be undefined behaviour.

This is one of the unsafe aspects of the language: you are abandoning the type system (because of the variable arguments), and so you abandon static correctness verifiability.

The safe way to print a string literally would be either `fputs(p, stdout)`, or (less efficiently perhaps) `printf("%s", p)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str = "hello";
printf(str);
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf("hello");
```

Just like:

```
char *format = "%s",
     *str = "hello";
printf(format, str);
```

is equivalent to:

```
char *str = "hello";
printf("%s",str);
```

... and whether you can truly rely on the content of `format` or not is completely different story.